# Implementing assignment operator in linked list stack

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack, deep-copy

I'm trying to do a deep copy assignment operator for a linked list stack. I think I've wrapped my head around what I need to do, but I can't quite get it.

Here is my code:

```
// Purpose: performs a deep copy of the data from rhs into this linked stack
// Parameters: rhs is linked stack to be copied
// Returns: *this
// Postconditions: this stack contains same data values (in the same order) as are in rhs; any memory previously used by this stack has been deallocated.
template <typename T>
const LinkedStack<T>& LinkedStack<T>::operator=(const LinkedStack<T>& rhs) {
    while(rhs.m_head != NULL) {
        m_head->m_data = rhs.m_head->m_data;
        m_head->m_next = new Node<T>();
        rhs.m_head = rhs.m_head->m_next;
        m_head = m_head->m_next;
    }
    m_size = rhs.m_size;
}
```

So my thought process is to copy the data, make a new node, and then pop a node off of the rhs variable.

It currently errors on "rhs.m_head = rhs.m_head->m_next;" for "error: assignment of member 'LinkedStack::m_head' in read-only object". I'm not sure how to work around this since I'm being passed a constant reference.

Where am I going wrong?

---

The node header (templated):

```
template <class T>
class Node {
public:
  T m_data;            // Data to be stored
  Node<T>* m_next;     // Pointer to the next element in the list

  Node() : m_next(NULL) {}
  Node(const T& x, Node<T>* p) : m_data(x), m_next(p) {}
};
```

The linked stack header (templated):

```
template <class T>
class LinkedStack {

  Node<T>* m_head;     // Pointer to the top of the stack
  int m_size;          // The number of elements in the stack

public:
  LinkedStack();
  ~LinkedStack();
  const LinkedStack<T>&  operator= (const LinkedStack<T>& rhs);    
  bool isEmpty() const;
  const T& top() const throw (Oops);
  void push(const T& x);  
  void pop();
  void clear();
};
```

---

EDIT: Found the solution.

```
template <typename T>
const LinkedStack<T>& LinkedStack<T>::operator=(const LinkedStack<T>& rhs) {
    clear();

    Node<T>* temp = rhs.m_head;

    m_head = new Node<T>();
    Node<T>* c_head = m_head;

    while(temp != NULL) {
        m_head->m_data = temp->m_data;
        temp = temp->m_next;
        m_head->m_next = new Node<T>;
        m_head = m_head->m_next;
    }

    m_head = c_head;
    m_size = rhs.m_size;

    return *this;
}
```

My major hangup was forgetting to reset m_head to the original head before I started using m_next.

Comment: You have a comment to the `operator=` function: "Returns: *this". But you never do.

Comment: As for your problem there are a few things you need to do which you dont: 1) Clear the *current* list. 2) Copy the list from `rhs` *without modifying* `rhs`. Remember that `rhs ` is a reference to a *constant* object.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the info. Although, how would I move down the stack without copying or modifying rhs?

Comment: *Temporary variables*. E.g. `auto tempp = rhs.m_head;` etc.